# Should I accept an answer when it doesn't answer the original question but explains how the question is invalid?

Tags: discussion

With the situation faced in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1675995/how-can-i-switch-from-uefi-to-bios), I want to know the general behavior on Superuser in case the original question is invalid. There is one of the answers that explain very well that the original question has no answer. Although the answer in consideration doesn't "answer" the original question, in literal terms, but it is the one that helped me the most.

Should I select this as the accepted answer?

Comment: "Although the answer in consideration doesn't "answer" the original question, in literal terms, but it is the one that helped me the most." - **It absolutely does answer your question.**

Answer (score 6):

"There is no way you can do this because..." *is* a valid answer. If you are starting from a potentially faulty assumption then having someone explain that fault and what, if anything, you can or cannot do about it then that is still an answer even if it does not provide the "solution" that you wanted.

Someone might come along in the future with the same or similar problems and if they are working from the same assumption then the answer can help them just as much as yourself.

So long as the answer is more than just "No you can't" and provides some explanation and/or reference to support the stance, then it is an answer.

But ultimately it is up to you what answer you accept.